# Random sound generator for a single button that uses 8 different .wav files. Each file is named sound1.wav, sound2.wav.... sound8.wav

Tags: arrays, swift, audio, uibutton

Got most of my information from other stackoverflow posts, but none really helped.

```
  import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class FaceButtonScreen: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var mainButton1: UIButton!

        var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Not sure if doing the array properly

```
        var arrayOfSounds = ["sound1", "sound2", "sound3", "sound4", "sound5", "sound6", "sound7", "sound8"]

        func setupAudioPlayer(file: NSString, type: NSString){

            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file as String, ofType: type as String)
            let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path!)
            do {
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            } catch {
                print("Player not available")
            }

        }


        }
```

There was a different function here that was connected to the button, but 
       displayed errors

```
    func faceButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            let range: UInt32 = UInt32(arrayOfSounds.count)
            let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
        let sound = arrayOfSounds.randomElement()
            self.setupAudioPlayer(arrayOfSounds[number], type: ".wav")
            self.audioPlayer?.play()



    //I need to understand how to complete the array and connect the sound files; any 
     help would be greatly appreciated
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some of my Swift code I dug up:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sound1", withExtension: "wav")
```

I think I see the issue:
You are passing in the type as ".wav" and not "wav"

**Answer**
 • Remove the period in the String: ".wav"